Is layer Composite Space the wrong way round in GIMP?
I've been looking into the GIMP Layers tab's "Composite Space" option, and I'm rather confused by it.  Given a background of white pixels and a foreground of black pixels at 50% opacity, I'd expect the RGB linear colour space to give me sample merged pixels of 128,128,128 because that's about 50% of 255,255,255.  However, with RGB (linear) selected I actually get pixels of 188,188,188 - significantly lighter.

When I select RGB (perceptual), though, I actually get the result I'd have expected from the linear model; pixels are darker at 128,128,128 - half way between white and black.

Is this a bug with GIMP's options here being the wrong way round, or am I misunderstanding something?

well, obviously it can mean 2 different things. So it can be from monitors point of view or files point of view which result in opposite results.

(188,188,188)(aka #bcbcbc) is actually the gray that is half as bright as white (ie, equivalent to a dense checkerboard pattern seen from afar) in the sRGB color space.

make sure you are seeing the image above at its native size, scaling by browsers will make the checkerboard look like (128,128,128)
In other words, you aren't taking in account the gamma encoding.

What's your point exactly?  Am I supposed to perceive the one on the right the same as the checkerboard, or the one on the left?  Though the one on the right is closer it's still not really the same.

Should be same as the one of the right. How "same" depends on your display. The better the display, the more similar. I have a laptop with a very good IPS screen and a somewhat random side screen, there is  some visible difference on the side screen but hardly any on the laptop.

An ImageSharp dev's take: "I'm not convinced GIMP is doing the correct thing (and this has nothing to do with sRGB). Pixel Composition requires alpha premultiplication and it does not appear to me that GIMP is performing that premultiplication."  He also notes that CSS results in the same output as ImageSharp.  GIMP is the odd one out in its default alpha blending behaviour.
